# Facebook Group API Invite member

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying all day to figure this out, but apparently it does not work for me.
What i'm looking into doing is ... ask for facebook login, and then add that user to a group ( send an invite ). I've tried to follow the API docs here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#invite_member
No luck.

My code looks like:

```
<?php
require "fb/facebook.php";

$access_token = "app_token_here";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'appId',
  'secret' => 'secretBlabla',
  'cookie' => true,
  'allowSignedRequest' => false,
));



$params = array('scope' => 'read_friendlists,read_insights,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_groups,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_relationships,user_website');
$fuser = $facebook->getUser();
if ($fuser) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api("/me");
    }  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $fuser = null;
    }
}

if ($fuser) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}

$page = "/XXXXXX/members/".$fuser;
$token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->api($page, "POST", array("access_token"=>$access_token)); // i've tried with $token as well
```

Error i get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#3) Unknown method\n
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: have u find solution ?? i m facing same problem.

Comment: please share if you already find the solution

Comment: nope, no solution yet :(